# Confused by Jaccard Similarity concept

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am going through item-item similarity and my professor said that if I have a popularity based collaborative filtering, then we need to normalize using the Jaccard similarity.

I have the following data

```
Jack watched movie 2, movie 1, movie 3

Bob watched movie 1 and movie 3

Tim watched movie 1
```

And For Tim we need to recommend the movies using item based collaborative filtering.

So the co-occurrence matrix based on the number of movies a user has seen  is:

```
                movie 1 movie 2 movie 3
movie 1              0        1      2

movie 2              1        0      1

movie 3              2        1      0
```

My professor says after normalization of above matrix using Jaccard similarity we get the following matrix:

```
                movie 1 movie 2 movie 3
movie 1             0       1/3     2/2

movie 2             1/3       0     1/2

movie 3             2/3       1/2    0
```

Can some one please explain why people who saw movie 1 and then movie 3 are not similar to someone who saw movie 3 and then movie 1?

Comment: Because If you saw movie 1 first before movie 3, you wouldn't be the same either :). Interesting question. I will have to follow this post to see why.